# Encode uploaded mp3 files in WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Is there a way to encode every MP3 file I've attatched in my WordPress site?
This is how the code looks when you go to source:

```
<ol class='songs'><li><a href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/f1678576.mp3' title='Song Title'>Artist - Song</a></li></ol>
```

PHP code:

```
if ($attachments) {
        echo "<ol class='songs'>";
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo "<li>";
            echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ol>";
    }
```

I saw WPaudio but don't know how to implement it. This is how the WPaudio code looks:

```
<pre><code><script type='text/javascript'>_wpaudio.enc['wpaudio-5019e1ff1c9da'] = '\u0068\u0074\u0074\u0070\u003a\u002f\u002f\u0075\u0072\u006c\u002e\u0074\u006f\u002f\u0079\u006f\u0075\u0072\u002e\u006d\u0070\u0033';</script><a id='wpaudio-5019e1ff1c9da' class='wpaudio wpaudio-enc' href='#'>Artist - Song</a></code></pre>
```

If you have any suggestions please feel free to express. Thank you.

Comment: Why need encode? You want to encode the file name?

Comment: Yes. because when you dig into the source code. Just a click and you'll get the file. :)

Comment: But even if you encode they can still get the file, what you see is what you get remember?

Comment: You really want to embed a few megabytes * 4 or so for encoding overhead in every page, killing any hope of cacheability? What's the url for your site, so I can blacklist it before it blows up my bandwidth bill?

Comment: In WPaudio code, there's no .mp3 file. That's my problem. I want to hide the .mp3 thingy on my source code.

Answer (score 0):

WPAudio looks fairly straightforward to install if this is how you want to go about things ... http://wpaudio.com/#install ... at the end of the day you're going to spend a lot of effort hiding a file name by encoding it when you could use another player.

If you're going to be that paranoid might as well use a service like SoundCloud http://soundcloud.com/